# Edit page with ID in GET does not exist resourcefull controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I cant seem to get my edit function to work in my resourceful controller. This is my controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller{

   public function index()
   {
      return view('testindex');
   }

   public function test(){
      return 'test';
   }

   public function edit(User $user){
      return 'test2';    
   }


   public function create(){
      return 'test3';    
   }
}
```

And my routes:

```
Route::post('test','UserController@test');     
Route::resource('/','UserController');
```

Which mean that edit should be in the resource controller.

Create works but edit isn't, it gives me a

> NotFoundHttpException

This is the form:

```
<a href="{{$id}}/edit">Edit</a>
```

And yes, the variable `$id` works and is showing in the url.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In your console if you type php artisan routes:list do you see the edit route?

Comment: @pascalzoet yes I do see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not naming the resource i.e.

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

To get around this you will need to change you route to be:

```
Route::resource('/', 'UserController', ['parameters' => [
    '' => 'user'
]]);
```

(The above will allow you to keep your urls the same).

Please note that you will have to keep this `Route` at the bottom of your file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's giving me: `Class App\Http\Controllers\User does not exist`

Comment: @Loko This is because you've not added the `use` statement in your `UserController` e.g. `use App\User;`

Comment: Yes thanks. I didnt know what was put in the controller functions was actually linked to the model that has to have the same name